# How to drill into List and get their parentIds

Tags: c#

I am facing an issue where I have to drill down through the list till I find the desired contentId. Once the contentId is matched, I need to get its ParentIds. I am able to get the contentId but not its ParentId.

Currently I am using recursion to get the ParentIds of a child node. But failed to get the desired results. 
Can anyone make it run, or provide the correct code to get this issue fixed. I'm trying to get the childnode and its parentIds. I need to get the parentIds and then want to insert into a List.

I'm able to drill down into the loop but don't know how and when to store the parentIds into a list.

In this code, I am trying to get the parents of contentId "5".

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Program obj = new Program();
                var data = obj.GetAllChildCats();
                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            public List<int> GetAllChildCats()
            {
                var ret = getdata();
                var data = GetAllChildCats(4, ret.contentObjects, 0);
                return data;
            }

            List<int> parentIdsList1 = new List<int>();

            private List<int> GetAllChildCats(int id, ContentObjects data, int Parentid)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.ContentObjectId.ToString()))
                {
                    parentIdsList1.Add(Parentid);
                    if (data.ContentObjectId == id)
                    {
                        return parentIdsList1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (data.ChildContentObjects != null)
                        {
                            foreach (ContentObjects cat in data.ChildContentObjects)
                            {
                                GetAllChildCats(id, cat, data.ContentObjectId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return parentIdsList1;
            }

            public Heirarchy getdata()
            {
                Heirarchy ret = new Heirarchy()
                {
                    _id = 11,
                    contentObjects = new ContentObjects()
                    {
                        ContentObjectId = 1,
                        NodeId = 34,
                        ChildContentObjects = new List<ContentObjects>()
                        {
                            new ContentObjects() {
                                ContentObjectId=2,
                                NodeId=34,
                                ChildContentObjects= new List<ContentObjects>()
                                {
                                    new ContentObjects() {
                                    ContentObjectId=3,
                                    NodeId=34,
                                    ChildContentObjects= null
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new ContentObjects() {
                                ContentObjectId=4,
                                NodeId=34,
                                ChildContentObjects= new List<ContentObjects>()
                                {
                                    new ContentObjects() {
                                    ContentObjectId=5,
                                    NodeId=34,
                                    ChildContentObjects= null
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    HierarchyId = 2
                };
                return ret;
            }
        }

        public class Heirarchy
        {
            public int _id { get; set; }
            public ContentObjects contentObjects { get; set; }
            public int HierarchyId { get; set; }   
        }

        public class ContentObjects
        {
            public int ContentObjectId { get; set; }
            public int NodeId { get; set; }
            public List<ContentObjects> ChildContentObjects { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: By "parents of contentId '5'"...do you mean "4" as in `var data = GetAllChildCats(4, ret.contentObjects, 0);`?

Comment: Yes,it should be var data = GetAllChildCats(5, ret.contentObjects, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this code, I am trying to get the parents of contentId "5".

This can be solved by a simple depth-first search. We just have to check the children's ID *before* digging deeper into the tree, so that we can still return the parent reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program obj = new Program();

    var parents = obj.GetParentsOf(5, obj.getdata().contentObjects);

    Console.WriteLine(parents.Count()); // yields 1
    Console.WriteLine(parents.First().ContentObjectId); // yields 4
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private IEnumerable<ContentObjects> GetParentsOf(int id, ContentObjects root)
{
    if (root.ChildContentObjects != null)
    {
        foreach (ContentObjects c in root.ChildContentObjects)
        {
            // If a direct child has the requested ID, we are a parent.
            if (c.ContentObjectId == id)
            {
                yield return root;
            }

            // Recurse deeper down.
            foreach (ContentObjects found in GetParentsOf(id, c))
            {
                yield return found;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If, on the other hand, by "parents" you mean the complete *path* down the tree, we need to modify the method as follows. We again have a recursive depth-first search, but we insert our own id into the path when returning from a successful recursive step:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program obj = new Program();

    var path = obj.GetPathTo(5, obj.getdata().contentObjects);

    // prints 1, 4
    foreach (ContentObjects o in path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.ContentObjectId);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// returns null if id could not be found
private IEnumerable<ContentObjects> GetPathTo(int id, ContentObjects root)
{
    if (root.ChildContentObjects != null)
    {
        foreach (ContentObjects c in root.ChildContentObjects)
        {
            if (c.ContentObjectId == id)
            {
                // If a direct child has the requested ID, we are the first parent.
                return new[] { root };
            }
            else
            {
                // Recurse deeper down.
                var found = GetPathTo(id, c);
                if (found != null)
                {
                    // We found something deeper down. Since we are part of the
                    // path, append own id.
                    return new[] { root }.Concat(found);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: In this approach we are only getting the parents. We aren't able to get the grandparents and their parents and so on. I want all the ParentIds to be stored in a list, so that I can use them further.

Comment: @Praveen: Ah, I see, then I misunderstood your requirements. Then we'll need a different approach. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @Praveen: I have added a version which returns the complete *path* to the object you are seeking. Is that what you had in mind?